# The desktop version of chat is broken on Android Chrome

Tags: bug, chat

The desktop version of chat looks like the following screenshot after the keyboard is used at least once:

[image]

It never worked very well on my tablet, but it was at least useable. The mobile version doesn't really make any sense on a tablet.

I'm using a Nexus 10 on Android 4.2 using the latest Chrome.

Comment: We don't support mobile Chrome.

Comment: @balpha which browsers on Android are supported? Chrome is the default browser for all Google Nexus devices.

Comment: We support the "normal" Android browser. I know that Google wants to make Chrome the standard, but as an Android user who regularly tests Chrome, I hope that it catches up with the stock browser in rendering and usability before Google pulls the plug (I didn't know they had already done that one some devices). I really want to support mobile Chrome soon (that's why I haven't given you a status-declined right away), but at the moment it's just way too broken.

Comment: @balpha you can't even install the aosp browser without root on the Nexus 10, and then you still need to use apks from questionable sources (or build it from sources, probably). It is rather annoying that chrome lags behind the stock browser on Android.